# How do I generate the SigV2 Signature for AWS S3 Buckets in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, signature

I am currently working on uploading to some S3 buckets. I am able to get a JSON containing the name of the bucket, access key, and secret key. I need the signature.

The Authorization header is currently supposed to look like this

Authorizaiton: AWS XYZ:signature

I have done some research on how to generate this sig and what sig type it is and my understanding is that this is a v2 sig not a v4. That being said, I have tried following the documentation for generating the signature but I'm having some trouble reproducing their results.

Does anyone know of a library or tutorial that I can use?

Comment: Why do you want to use V2? V4 is now the standard and V2 is not supported in all AWS regions. There are numerous examples on StackOverflow for creating both V2 and V4 AWS signatures in Python and many other languages. The Search Bar is your friend.

Comment: I've looked around stack overflow and just can't seem to find any solid examples. And I am not the one deciding on V2 or V4, the product I'm working with seems to be on V2. 

Actually, if you know, does V2 and V4 have the same Auth header signature? As in AWS XYZ:Signature

Comment: AWS publishes complete examples on their website. StackOverflow has dozens. Do a google search for AWS Python Signature. Hundreds of examples. The AWS Signature starts with AWS4. Any AWS region that supports V2 also support V4.